# AngularJS routeParams - file not found exception

Tags: angularjs

Following is my example

```
var myApp = angular.module('MySampleApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.controller('SampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams',     function($scope, $routeParams) {
$scope.employee = {
    id: 5,
    name : 'balaji',
    sal : 5000
};

$scope.a = $routeParams.a;
$scope.b = $routeParams.b;

}]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    template : "<strong> This is my routeProvider sample </strong>"
}) 
.when('/calc/:a/:b', {
    templateUrl: "calc.htm",
    controller: "SampleCtrl"
})
.otherwise({
    template : "<strong> No CONTENT </strong>"
})
}]);

a01.htm
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MySampleApp">
<head>
    <title>RoteParams example</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8    /angular-route.js"></script>

<script src="SampleCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="SampleCtrl">
        {{employee.id}} , {{employee.name}} , {{employee.sal}}
        <div>
            <a href="#/calc/4/5"> Sum </a>
        </div>
        <div ng-view> </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have installed npm and started server using following commands:

```
C:\Users\xyz>http-server c:\Users\xyz\Descktop\practice
Starting up http-server, serving c:\Users\xyz\Descktop\practice
Available on:
  http://10.0.0.117:8081
  http://127.0.0.1:8081
```

When I try to access the page a01.htm through `http://localhost:8081/a01.htm` and `http://localhost:8081/a01.htm#/calc/4/5`, 
both the links are throwing

> "This localhost page can’t be found
>
> No web page was found for the web address:     http://localhost:8081/a01.htm"

Also, on server it shows:

> pleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36" [Sat Dec 24 2016 19:54:07 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard
>   Time)] "GET /a01.htm" Error (404): "Not found"

Comment: Are you sure that the server started?

Comment: Yes I started the server..otherwise how come its listening to the URL GET/a01.htm ?

Comment: What is the output of `dir c:\Users\xyz\Descktop\practice` ?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I did was instead of using a path like

```
c:\xyz\desktop\practice
```

and starting http-server, I did the following:

step 1:

```
c:\
```

step 2:

```
http-server c:\xyz\desktop\practice
```

It started working. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
127.0.0.1 8081
```

Use this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8081/wamp/www/Angular_1/contactapp/
```